# MySQL 1300 Invalid big5 character string: ' \xC3\x97 '

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have no clue what's going on here. One of my DB servers is giving me that error when trying to create a function (that works on all the other servers):

My function is

```
delimiter $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `getreadablesize`(`Width` DECIMAL(13,4),`Height` DECIMAL(13,4),`Type` VARCHAR(64)) RETURNS varchar(64) CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
BEGIN

RETURN concat(trim(trailing'.'
        from trim(trailing'0'
            from`Width`)),'\"',
    if(`Height`>0,concat(' × ',trim(trailing'.'
                from trim(trailing'0'
                    from`Height`)),'\"'),''),
    if(`Type`>'',concat(' ',`Type`),''));
END$$
```

And the exact error message is

> 0 row(s) affected, 2 warning(s): 1300 Invalid big5 character string: '
>   \xC3\x97 ' 1300 Invalid big5 character string: 'C39720'

None of my DB is in Chinese, or ever uses the Big5 character set?

If I copy my schema create code, I get this:

```
CREATE DATABASE `sterling` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci */;
```

---

**EDIT:** It works if I change the times symbol to something else, but that still doesn't make any sense as to why it's being treated as Big5 and not uft8

---

**EDIT:** Something is apparently quite wrong. If I run the following query, this is what I get:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';

+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| 'character_set_client',     | 'big5'                       |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| 'character_set_connection', | 'big5'                       |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| 'character_set_database',   | 'utf8mb4'                    |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| 'character_set_filesystem', | 'binary'                     |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| 'character_set_results',    | 'big5'                       |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| 'character_set_server',     | 'utf8mb4'                    |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| 'character_set_system',     | 'utf8'                       |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| 'character_sets_dir',       | '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/' |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
```

But my `my.cnf` clearly has `default-character-set = utf8mb4` and all the variants of it under each applicable section... I will restart my MySQL server, because something is most definitely a foot.

Comment: Check `SHOW CREATE FUNCTION getreadablesize` -- perhaps it was created as big5 long ago.

Comment: Add `SET NAMES utf8mb4;`

Answer (score 0):

Welp. I restarted the server and it never came back. I tried just about every MySQL server repair steps that existed and just nothing worked. Eventually I got it to start in safe mode with the innodb force flag set to 6, and I was then able to use HeidiSQL to pull all the data out (mysqlddump just hung and never started, but HeidiSQL implements their own export.). Even then though I still had 3 of my 165 tables that I couldn't read at all.